# Why does my computer keep installing Stage 3 of 3 (complete) and then reboot?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

Before the desktop is displayed, my computer displays a message:

```
(1) Installing update 3 of 3 (0%)
(2) Installing update 3 of 3 (100%) complete
(3) It then reboots itself and goes back to #1
```

Even if I select to boot into Safe Mode, it does #1 above.

How can I stop my computer from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason restore fails to get it booting, load the recovery environment command prompt and
type

Del C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml

hit enter key

exit recovery environment and restart the pc, you may get 3 of 3 again but be patient, the desktop should load.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of this file, but it makes sense. +1 for teaching me something new.

Comment: I forget where I learned that, oh well I guess it does not matter, at least I remembered where my note for it was :-) .

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly "common" problem, you should use a Vista (recovery) disk to "Repair" your installation by restoring the system to a point before the updates were installed. (System Restore) Then re-install the updates.

Get your Vista recovery disk here: http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/

Answer (score 0):

See this Microsoft Support article: [An update is not installed successfully when you try to install the update in Windows Vista and Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949358).  What you want to do is either repair the system using the Windows installation DVD, or restore the system from the previous restore point.  If you are running Windows Vista, you will also need to install a patch at the bottom of the support page.

> To resolve this problem, use the following methods in the order in which they are presented. Method 1 is the simplest fix, and method 3 [*sic*] is the most complex.
>
> - Method 1: Start Windows with the Windows installation media, and then use the Repair feature
> - Method 2: Start the system in safe mode, and then use the System Restore feature